# Join 6 tables, but multiple one to many relationships

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports, multiple-tables

I have a question regarding joining 6 tables together.

So the six tables are:

1. INTran (details of each item's transaction include receiving, invoice sales, credit return, etc.)
2. ShipHeader
3. ShipLine (ShipHeader and ShipLine is a one to many relationship joining through ShipperID)
4. PurchaseOrder
5. PurchaseOrderDetail (PurchaseOrder and PurchaseOrderDetail is a one to many relationship join through PONbr)
6. Inventory

So What I am trying to do is to make a report in Crystal Report, and:

1. calculate on hand with INTran Table (Transaction Date and Qty)
2. Calculate Qty Shortfall with ShipHeader and ShipLine table (only ShipLine has both Qty Ordered and Qty Shipped data. INTran only has Qty Shipped data so I cannot calculate Qty Shortfall, but ShipHeader has the Invoice Date to control the Invoice date range in ShipLine Table)
3. Extract different Purchase Orders

So here is the problem:

I need to get desired data for qty sold, qty shortfall, purchase orders (and qty for each PO), but I have three different transaction dates:

1. TranDate in INTran
2. Invoice Date in ShipHeader
3. PO Date in PurchaseOrder

So how do I put all these transaction dates together?

And also, INTran, ShipLine, PurchaseOrderDetail, and Inventory all have the InventoryID field, how do I join them together?

I tried one method:

PurchaseOrder <--> PurchaseOrderDetail <--> Inventory <--> INTran <--> Inventory <--> ShipLine <--> ShipHeader

But this does not work since the calculated qty become much bigger than reality.

Thanks everyone. I appreciate your time and help. Lemme know if there is anything unclear.

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: What is the issue here? is your data getting duplicated?

Comment: Yes you are right. So when I calculate data from ShipLine Table the number gets much bigger and reality. And can I use TranDate in INTran Table to Control ShipLine and PurChaseOrderDetail talbles?

Comment: Try select diistict records option in database tab

Comment: Hi Thank you Siva. But I am using this in the Crystal Report, and it refers to a problem of using different transaction dates (TranDate in INTran, Invoice Date in ShipHeader, PODate in PurchaseOrder). I am not sure if I can only use the TranDate in INTran to control other tables?